# I need help with a PXE Server on Ubuntu 22.04 using dnsmasq

Tags: boot, server, 22.04, pxe, dnsmasq

I am currently trying to setup a PXE server on a ubuntu22.04 server to install iso's or any other images via networkboot/pxeboot.

I use dnsmasq for that and have encountered some problems.

first, sometimes the booting laptop gets a tftp timeout after i edited something and edited it back.

second when it gets through to boot it loads kernel and initrd for ubuntu 22.04 fine but gets stuck with: /init line 49 can't open /dev/sr0 no medium found.

Here is my dnsmasq.conf:

```
#dnsmasq.conf

dhcp-no-override
interface=enp5s0f2,lo
port=0
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.42.100,192.168.42.200,255.255.255.0,8h
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0

pxe-service=x86PC, "Boot from network", pxelinux.0
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/srv/tftp
```

and my /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/default:

```
DEFAULT install
LABEL install
        KERNEL /mnt/casper/vmlinuz
        INITRD /mnt/casper/initrd
        APPEND boot=casper ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.42.10:/home/lucca iso-scan/filename=ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

I got all this from multiple sources and would like some guidance from someone who already did a pxe server, as i dont really understand what i am doing